# sas looping through the dataset make the value missing depending on first row

Tags: sas

I have a dataset similiar to this.I am not sure how many coulmns I would get or rows as it is part of the code. But I will have the first value to be equal to 0 bucket.

```
DATA MY_data;
INPUT bucket D_201503 D_201504 ;
DATALINES;
0 1000 20500
1 200 6700
2 101 456
3 45 567
;
```

eg -In this dataset I want the values below 10% of the first row value should be missing. like for eg first value is 1000 for bucket 0 so 45 should be missing. The same for 20500 as well.Anything below 10% should be missing. The dataset is generally not huge but need to determine columns and rows.
So I should get this as

```
0 1000 20500
1 200 6700
2 101 .
3 . .
```

I am not sure how I should loop through the dataset and make this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATA MY_data;
INPUT bucket D_201503 D_201504 ;
DATALINES;
0 1000 20500
1 200 6700
2 101 456
3 45 567
;

data want;
set MY_data;
array row(*) _all_;
array _first_row(999); /*any number >= the number of columns of MY_data*/
/*we read the first line and store the values in _first_row array*/
retain _first_row:;
if _n_ = 1 then do i=1 to dim(row);
    _first_row(i) = row(i);
end;
/*replacing values <10% of the first row*/
else do i=1 to dim(row);
    if upcase(vname(row(i))) ne "BUCKET" and row(i) < 0.1*_first_row(i) then row(i) = .;
end;
drop i _first_row:;
run;
```

Comment: Using a `_temporary_` `array` as Tom and user667489 shows is even better than `retain` and `drop`. It's never too late to learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Find out how many variables there are (assume we just want all vars prefixed D_)*/
data _null_;
  set my_data(obs = 1);
  array vars_of_interest(*) D_:;
  call symput(dim(vars_of_interest),"nvars")
run;

/*Save bucket 0 values to a temp array, compare each row and set missing values*/    
data want;
  set my_data;
  array bucket_0(&nvars) _temporary_;
  array vars_of_interest(*) D_:;
  do i = 1 to &nvars;
    if bucket = 0 then bucket_0[i] = vars_of_interest[i];
    else if vars_of_interest[i] < bucket_0[i] / 100 then call missing(vname(vars_of_interest[i]))
  end; 
run;
```

Comment: getting this error for first part of code :ERROR: Symbolic variable name   2 must begin with a letter or underscore

Comment: Sorry, got the arguments in the wrong order for call symput. Try swapping them.

Comment: It runs but not getting any missing values just an additional column was created as i with value 3,  WARNING 134-185: Argument #1 is an expression, which cannot be updated by the MISSING subroutine call.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to remember the values from the first row (or perhaps from the row where BUCKET=0?) so that you can then compare the value from the first row to the current value.  A temporary ARRAY is an easy way to do that.

So assuming that BUCKET is always the first numeric variable in your data then you can just do something like this.

```
data want ;
  set my_data;
  array x _numeric_;
  array y (1000) _temporary_;
  do i=2 to dim(x);
    if bucket=0 then y(i)=x(i);
    else if x(i) < y(i) then x(i)=.;
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

If BUCKET is not the first variable then you could add `retain bucket;` before the `set` statement to force it to be the first.  Or change the first array statement to list the specific variables you want to process, just remember to change the lower bound on the DO loop.

If you have more than a thousand variables then increase the dimension of the temporary array.